# Symfony2: cannot submit form with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

I am trying to submit a form created with symfony2 through an ajax call.
I know there are plenty of tutorials out there, but I think I am doing everything right and still can not manage to make it work.

Here is my code in the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/preferences", name="_mybundle_preferences")
 * @Template()
 */
public function preferencesAction(Request $request)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $allprefs = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyPrefs')
                ->findAllPrefs();

    // Creating the form
    $defaultData = array();
    $formpref = $this->container
            ->get('form.factory')
            ->createNamedBuilder(
                'formpref', 
                'form', 
                $defaultData, 
                array('validation_groups' => array())
            );

    // Input the search field 
    // (will be connected to a jQuery function to filter results)
    $formpref->add('search', 'search', array( 'mapped' => false) );

    // Populate the list of choice fields where the user can select its 
    // preferences
    foreach ( $allprefs as $mypref)
    {
            $fieldname = $mypref->getId();
            $formpref->add($fieldname, 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array( 
                    '3' => 'Very', 
                    '2' => 'Quite', 
                    '1' => 'Poor', 
                    '0' => 'None'
                    ), 
                'expanded'    => false, 
                'label'       => $mypref->getName(),
                ));
    }

    // Just temporary, I want to remove it through ajax
    $formpref->add('send', 'submit');    

    // Get the form
    $formpref = $formpref->getForm();

    // Handle the request
    $formpref->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formpref->isValid()) {

        // do stuff

        $response = array("success" => true);
        return new Response(json_encode($response));

    }

    $result = array(
      'forms' => $formpref->createView(),
      );

    return $result;

}
```

In my twig:

```
<div id="div1" data-path="{{path('_mybundle_preferences')}}">
</div>

    {{ form(forms) }}
```

And the jQuery script

```
$("select").change( function(){

    // I am using an array to check how many output requests I already made
    var myArray = [];

    myArray.push( 1 ); 

    $("#div1").html("Saving...");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $('#div1').data('path'),
        data: $("#formpref").serialize() ,
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            myArray.pop();
            if (myArray.length === 0) { 
                $("#div1").html("All changes saved"); 
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
          console.log('Error : ' + errorThrown);
        },
    });

    return false;
});
```

Through some file_put_contents inserted in the code ( and not shown here) I can 
see that the $formpref->isValid() call never returns true when the form is 
submitted with ajax, but works fine when submitted with normal submit button.

I also tried to send the results to a different route, but same outcome...

What am I doing wrong? I am running in circles...

Answer (score 0):

I think that `$("#formpref").serialize()` might be the issue. Try this code to serialize your form:

```
var values = {};
var $form = $("#formpref"); //I assume formpref is id of your form
$.each($form.serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
    values[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

and then post it all using:

```
$.ajax({
    data: values ,
    (...)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, i still get the same... $formpref->isValid() returns false...
In addition $formpref->getErrorsAsString() is returning an empty string with both my and your solution...

Comment: what errors do you get as form errors? Do you have your csrf token generated and passed via ajax call?

Comment: Thanks to your solution I finally found the error. 
I was actually sending no data. The form was generated in an odd way, with a div with id="formpref" that was empty. I had to select the form by name. I got confused since I saw the id="formfood", but did not realize it was empty. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @Alberto: This could be the issue when having multiple DOM elements with same ID ;)